# Passing a command as a variable to a function in Unix

Tags: bash, function, unix, parameters

Can you pass a command as a variable to another function? If yes, what is the syntax?

My code looks something like.

```
function1(){

for a in $1 
do
   echo $a
done
}

function2(){

function1 "ls -lrt folder/Name | grep 'foo' | grep 'bar'"

}
```

But this doesn't work. I even tried passing it as:

```
function1 `ls -lrt folder/Name | grep 'foo' | grep 'bar'`
```

But this passes only the first value of the command (and I understand why this happens).

Does anyone know the syntax to pass a command to function as a variable?

Comment: when you say `for a in $1` in `function1` it means that you are just going through the first parameter. If you want to loop through all the parameters, you need to use `$@`.

Comment: The above comment is correct, you could also just leave out the for loop and just do `echo @a` - if you intend to pass only that one string/function

Comment: I tried it, it works! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: What if the function1 takes multiple parameters? And the command is the third parameter being passed, then using $@ takes in some unnecessary values. How do I take values from say $3 onwards?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in comments, you are using `$1` but this will just contain the first parameter. Instead, you need to use `$@`.

From [Bash Manual → 3.4.2 Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters):

> **$@**
>
> ($@) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
>   separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" …. If the
>   double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the
>   first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>   word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
>   part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters,
>   "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

Then you ask

> What if the function1 takes multiple parameters? And the command is
>   the third parameter being passed, then using $@ takes in some
>   unnecessary values. How do I take values from say $3 onwards?

For this, you want to use [`shift`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

```
$ cat myscript.sh
#!/bin/bash
shift 2

echo "$@"
$ ./myscript.sh a b c d
c d
```

> **shift**
>
> ```
>  shift [n]
> ```
>
> Shift the positional parameters to the left by n. The positional
>   parameters from n+1 … $# are renamed to $1 … $#-n. Parameters
>   represented by the numbers $# to $#-n+1 are unset. n must be a
>   non-negative number less than or equal to $#. If n is zero or greater
>   than $#, the positional parameters are not changed. If n is not
>   supplied, it is assumed to be 1. The return status is zero unless n is
>   greater than $# or less than zero, non-zero otherwise.